# Chrome bookmark to switch to tab

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I, like many people have a whole bunch of bookmarks on my toolbar in chrome to things like gmail, google music, google calendar etc..

Often these pages are already open in a tab, however I'm the kind of person who has 100s of tabs open at one time.

Is there an easy way to make chrome switch to an existing tab of gmail when I click on the bookmark rather than spawning a new tab with gmail in? If not, is there a way to program this in using javascript or something on the bookmark?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Prevent Duplicate Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prevent-duplicate-tabs/eangilbdbecadgeclbehnkibpmedaoih), set options to keep old tab (blue arrow icon). If you'll need to make a dupe, disable by clicking on the icon till arrow is red, then don't forget to return it to blue.

For stuff like you listed you can just pin them which will make it clear you don't need to open second instance.

Comment: nice, bit tinkering with disabling when you intentionally need dup is tedious and awful. Would better have an exemption for that option…

Comment: Sadly, that extension is no more and I'm yet to find a replacement